# Code works on local server but not on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

The below code searches for products on an app I'm building. In my local server the search can be made case insensitive but not on heroku

```
def index
  if params[:q]
    search_term = params[:q]
    @products = Product.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search_term}%")
  else
    @products = Product.all
  end
end
```

how can i fix this? I need it to be case insensitive.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What database do you use on your machine? Do you use Postgres on Heroku?

Comment: Yes I use Postgres on Heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
search_term = params[:q].downcase
```

or

```
search_term = params[q:].upcase
```

thereby sanitizing the inputs.